# Using regex in redshift to find dollar values

Tags: redshift, regex

I have a field in a Redshift table that has user-generated text.  The field is where users can say how much they think something costs.

Ideally it'd just be a decimal, but it's varchar.  So users can type
"I think this is worth \$25", or "I'd pay 55" or "\$117".

So I'm trying to use `regexp_substr` to pull this out.  Specifically `regexp_substr(f.comment_text, '\\$?[0-9]*')`.  But this doesn't work on a subset of entries for some reasons (eg `Could do for $115`).

If I remove the `?` it works on that, but no longer on entries that don't use `$`.  Why?  And what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting that you want extract numbers with either '$' or even not without a dollar.

Why are not using just [0-9]+ for that field? The results will be like

```
    some $1 something >> ['1']
    some other 115 >> ['115']
    $115 some thing >> ['115']
```

If you want to include '\$' sign, then '\$' can be repeated zero or once or by typo more, then regex would be

```
    \$*[0-9]+
```

which outputs

```
    some $1 something >> ['$1']
    some other 115 >> ['115']
    $115 some thing >> ['$115']
```

If this is not what you want, comment.

Hope this helps.

I would recommend using online regex matchers like [here](http://rubular.com/). They have short and sweet references which really help us get to the context.

Comment: If I do just `regexp_substr(comment_text, '[0-9]*')` it won't pull any rows with  just a dollar figure, eg `$123`.

Comment: @ScottieB u want number finally or number including the sign as in case 2 of my answer?

Comment: no dollar sign.  Case 2 is what I'm aiming for

Comment: Is number with no dollar is all u want from text even though there exists a dollar, then case 1 should do. With dollar u need the output - case2. Isn't ur comment contradicting?

Comment: I tried ur $123 case n the output was 123 via regex 1.

Comment: That's great!  I'm not sure how to implement that in Redshift.